# Getting value after pressing OK in showConfirmDialog

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have got the following problem:

Running the code below will produce a `JFrame` that will allow you to enter two values: one number and one list. 
This appears to be working correctly.

The issue is there doesn't seem to be a chance for the user to input values causing the `System.out.println` to output `null`.

```
public class naamEnBriefSelecter extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
private String ingevoerdeCodnummer;
private String soortBriefIngevoerd;
private JLabel codNR;
private JLabel soortBrief;
private JTextField invoerCodnummer;
private JComboBox<String> cb;
private int keuze;
private boolean klaar;





public void GUI(Container paneel) {
    klaar = false;

    paneel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();

    //JLabel
    codNR = new JLabel("Geef hier het Codicillen nummer op");
    soortBrief = new JLabel("Geef hier het soortBrief op");

    invoerCodnummer = new JTextField(20);
    String[] brieven = {"test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"};
    cb = new JComboBox<String>(brieven);

    JButton opslaan = new JButton("Opslaan");

    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    constraints.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);

    // add components to the panel
    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 0;
    paneel.add(codNR, constraints);

    constraints.gridx = 1;
    paneel.add(invoerCodnummer, constraints);

    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 1;
    paneel.add(soortBrief, constraints);

    constraints.gridx = 1;
    paneel.add(cb, constraints);

    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 2;
    constraints.gridwidth = 2;
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    paneel.add(opslaan, constraints);



        opslaan.addActionListener(this);

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    keuze = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "De volgende gegevens zijn ingevoerd: " + invoerCodnummer.getText() + " als codicillen nummer en de volgende soort brief: "
           + cb.getSelectedItem().toString() + "\n" + "Kloppen deze gegevens?");
   if (keuze == 0) {
        setter(invoerCodnummer.getText());
      System.out.println(invoerCodnummer.getText());
      System.exit(0);
   }


}


public void setter(String codnr) {
    this.ingevoerdeCodnummer = codnr;

}

public String getCodNr() {
    return ingevoerdeCodnummer;
}

public void laatZien() {
    //Create and set up the window.

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Naam en Soort Brief selecteer");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //Set up the content pane.
    GUI(frame.getContentPane());

    //Display the window.
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    naamEnBriefSelecter a = new naamEnBriefSelecter();           
        a.laatZien();       
    System.out.println(a.getCodNr()); // here should be the value comming from ingevoerdeCodnummer

}
}
```

Comment: Move the output into `actionPerformed` or let `laatZien()` return your number?

Comment: Use a modal dialog rather than JFrame

Comment: @StanislavL Cann you give me an exapmle?

Comment: @moritzg tried, but without succes..

Comment: how do you want to get the value in another class?

Comment: I need it, in the other class, as an input for another method.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem now is that the main execute immediately and don't wait
>   for the user input

Why is the `println` statement is inside `main()` method? It should be in `actionPerformed` method.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

 keuze = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "De volgende gegevens zijn ingevoerd: " + invoerCodnummer.getText() + " als codicillen nummer en de volgende soort brief: " + cb.getSelectedItem().toString() + "\n" + "Kloppen deze gegevens?");
 if (keuze == 0) {
  setter(invoerCodnummer.getText());
  System.out.println(invoerCodnummer.getText());
  System.exit(0);
 } else {
  System.out.println(getCodNr()); < --- You should put it here
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But i want to use the value invoerCodnummer in anthoder class. How can I retrieve this one?

Answer (score 0):

```
          naamEnBriefSelecter nebs = new naamEnBriefSelecter();
          nebs.laatZien();
          connr =  nebs.getCodNr();
          System.out.println(connr);
```

For example, I use this code in another class to open the windows created in `naamEnBriefSelecter`, which works fine. But variable `connr` is still `null`. How do I get the filled in value coming from `naamEnBriefSelecter`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. If this is part of the question, edit the question and add it.